# How to create breaks using the cut function without numbers overlapping

Tags: r, statistics, cut

I have a dataset and need to cut the age factor of my dataset into 3 different age categories...e.g. age group 1 (10-20 years old), age group 2 (21-30 years old), and age group 3 (31-40 years old).

If I type
`breaks=c(10, 20, 30, 40)` when creating the cut function, the outcome is as follows:
age group 1 being 10-20
age group 2 being 20-30
age group 3 being 30-40

I do not want this! I need age group 2 to be from 21-30 years of age (however 20 is part of this age category now)...I would appreciate some help thank you

Comment: It is not part of that category: `(20,30]` means greater than 20, less or equal than 30. Consequently individuals with an age of 20 will fall into group 1 only and 21 year olds fall in group 2.

Comment: Thank you for this! How about if I want my 3 age groups to be
age group 1 = 10-19 years old
age group 2 = 20-30 years old

Comment: See comment below the answer...

Comment: You can also set a non-integer break. Say, 19.5... it won't be any different if your data is all integers, but maybe it will be clearer?

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are misinterpreting the results.   The intervals are half-open.  They include the upper bound, but not the lower bound. So

```
 age = sample(10:40, 50, replace=TRUE)
 cut(age, breaks=c(10, 20, 30, 40))
 [1] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40] (20,30] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40]
 [8] (30,40] (10,20] (30,40] (20,30] (30,40] (30,40] (10,20]
[15] (10,20] (30,40] (30,40] (20,30] (30,40] (30,40] (20,30]
[22] (30,40] (30,40] (30,40] (10,20] (20,30] (10,20] (10,20]
[29] (10,20] (10,20] (20,30] (10,20] (20,30] (30,40] (20,30]
[36] (20,30] (20,30] (20,30] (10,20] (30,40] (20,30] (20,30]
[43] (10,20] (20,30] (20,30] (30,40] (30,40] (20,30] (10,20]
[50] (20,30]
Levels: (10,20] (20,30] (30,40]
```

Means that the number 20 is only in the first group (10,20] 
but not in the second group (20,30]
Also notice that the default does not include the lower limit so better than what I wrote before is `cut(age, breaks=c(10, 20, 30, 40), include.lowest = TRUE)` which will make the lowest level be the fully closed interval [10,20].

Comment: Thank you for this! How about if I want my 3 age groups to be
age group 1 = 10-19 years old
age group 2 = 20-30 years old
age group 3 = 31-40 years old
? Thank you!

Comment: `cut(x, breaks=c(10, 19, 30, 40), include.lowest = T)`

Comment: So lets say breaks=c(10, 19, 30, 40)
I want 3 categories, cat1 (10-18 yrs), cat2 (19-30 yrs) and cat3 (31-40) - how would I do this please?

Comment: cut(x, breaks=c(10, 18, 30, 40), include.lowest = T)

Comment: thank you. When I do this and do the summary function of it, the 3 categories appear as: [10-18] [18-30] [30-40], does this not mean they are overlapping?

Comment: ?? That is not what I get.  I get `Levels: [10,18] (18,30] (30,40]`  so that 18 is not in (18,30]  and 30 is not in (30,40]   The "(" means that the endpoint is not included. "]" means that the endpoint is included.

Comment: oh excuse me, I wrote it incorrectly. My output for the summary is like yours as you said above then [10-18] (18-30] (30-40] ... does this mean that group 1 ranges from 10-18, group 2 ranges from 19-30, and that group 3 ranges from 31-40? Thanks in advance

Comment: To understand the notation, it may help to look at this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))

Comment: Many thanks - how very helpful!! Happy holidays to you

Comment: what does 'include.lowest = T' mean/do please?

Comment: If you do not include that parameter (i.e. use the default `include.lowest = F`),   the intervals do _not_ include the lowest value.   With  `include.lowest = T` you get Levels: [10,18] (18,30] (30,40]  with `include.lowest = F`  you get Levels: (10,18] (18,30] (30,40]  
   - -  [10,18] means 10-18. (10,18]  means 11-18.  So if your data has the value 10 and you use (10,18], 10 does not go in _any_ group. Mostly that is not what you want, so you use `include.lowest = T` to get [10,18]

Comment: Thank you so much, extremely helpful - very well explained!