Binning Continuous Variable to Discrete Without Overlapping Values
I've been struggling to find a way to bin continuous variables as discrete without the ranges overlapping. I've looked at cut_interval/cut_number/cut_width from ggplot2, as well as other custom functions from StackOverflow, but what drives me nuts are when bins have overlapping values e.g. 1-5, 5-10, 10-15. For my purposes each bin needs to be exclusive e.g. 1-4, 5-10, 11-15.
Code chunk below is what I've worked out so far. It allows me to set X bins, roughly equal in value range, but I still get bins with overlapping values. I would end up using this when making a choropleth map for example.
make_bins <- function(x, bins){
  
  maxVal <- max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  minVal <- min(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  if(maxVal %% 2 == 0){
    maxVal
  } else {
    maxVal <- maxVal + 1
  }
  
  width <- maxVal / bins
  
  breaks <- seq(minVal, maxVal, by = width)
  breaks <- c(breaks, Inf)
  
  labels <- sapply(1:bins, function(i) {
    sprintf("%s-%s", round(breaks[i], 2), round(breaks[i + 1], 2))
  })
  last_one <- max(length(labels))
  labels[last_one] <- sprintf(">%s", breaks[last_one])
  
  out <- cut(x, breaks = breaks, labels = labels, right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)

  return(out)
}

Here's an example of how it could be used:
values <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)

values_binned <- make_bins(values, bins = 4)

table(values_binned)


If you use cut the intervals do not overlap, can you post an example where they do? See the help page on open and closed intervals' end points.

Related question, which also defends the default practice without giving you what you are asking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304960/how-to-create-breaks-using-the-cut-function-without-numbers-overlapping

I think what you want is offered by the Hmisc::cut2 function using the g ("g" for number of groups) parameter:
install.packages('Hmisc')
library(Hmisc)
values_binned <- cut2(values, g = 4)
table(values_binned)
values_binned
#[0.0103,0.214) [0.2143,0.437) [0.4374,0.694) [0.6943,0.984] 
#            25             25             25             25 


The cut functions do not make overlapping bins. In the following example, the bins are defined by
0.000625 <= value <= 0.332
0.332 < value <= 0.663
0.663 < value <= 0.994
That is, the ( symbol means >,
the [ symbol means >=,
the ] symbol means <=
Does that meet your needs?
set.seed(123)
values <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
min(values)
#> [1] 0.0006247733
max(values)
#> [1] 0.9942698
CutValues <- ggplot2::cut_interval(values, n = 3)
table(CutValues)
#> CutValues
#> [0.000625,0.332]    (0.332,0.663]    (0.663,0.994] 
#>               33               33               34

Created on 2024-11-22 with reprex v2.1.1

It does/does not meet my needs. I like that the values within the bin do not overlap, but the labels are what get me. I guess I should have been more direct in my original post that the labels too need to specify the values per bin are exclusive.

How would this look in practice? Suppose one group goes from 2 to 2.9999999 and the next starts at 3.00000000 -- would you prefer it say the first group runs 2-2.9999999 instead of seeing [2, 3)? I think your idea works well for integers, but the default behavior seems more generalizable.
